# How to change root URL configuration in order to use a namespace for the user URLs

Tags: django, django-authentication

Site-Wide URL:

```
from user import urls as user_urls
app_name='user'

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^user/',include(user_urls)),    
]
```

Since the **admin** app, also defines URL patterns named `login` and `logout` in `django/contrib/admin/sites.py`. I need Django pointing to **user** app.

It's still pointing towards `registration/login.html` (i.e admin app). I tried namespacing but its been removed in Django 2.0.

user/urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'',RedirectView.as_view()),

    re_path(
        r'^login/$',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='user/login.html'), 
        name='login'
    ),

    re_path(
        r'^logout/$',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='user/logged_out.html') 
, 
        {
            'extra_context':{'form':AuthenticationForm }
        }, name='logout'
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the URLs by namespace in django 2 you need to move you `app_name` attribute so `user/urls.py` would become;

```
app_name = 'user'
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', RedirectView.as_view()),

    re_path(
        r'^login/$',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), 
        {'template_name':'user/login.html'},
        name='login'
    ),

    re_path(
        r'^logout/$',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), 
        {
            'template_name':'user/logged_out.html',
            'extra_context':{'form':AuthenticationForm }
        },
        name='logout'
    ),
]
```

The URLs defined in `users.urls` will have an application namespace of `user`.

Alternatively you could namespace URLs in the same file by doing;

```
user_patterns = ([
    path(r'', RedirectView.as_view()),

    re_path(
        r'^login/$',auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), 
        {'template_name':'user/login.html'},
        name='login'
    ),

    re_path(
        r'^logout/$',auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), 
        {
            'template_name':'user/logged_out.html',
            'extra_context':{'form':AuthenticationForm }
        },
        name='logout'
    ),
], 'user')

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^user/', include(user_patterns)),    
]
```

The docs on this can be found here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs