# Can I reference project URLs in Django templates by providing the project name?

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project called `reports` with apps `report_1`, `report_2` etc.

For certain reasons, I want to treat the project as an app, so I have added `reports` to `INSTALLED_APPS` alongside `report_1` and `report_2` and also created `views.py` file and `templates` folder in the main project folder (where `settings.py` sit).

In the `urls.py` I have added `app_name = reports`.

However, calling the url from within template will work only if I skip the app name: so `{% url 'reports:index' %}` will throw

> 'reports' is not a registered namespace'

error, but `{% url 'index' %}` will work.

Why is that so? I thought Django traverses all apps listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`, looks for `app_name` (which is provided) and matches it with URL name.

Comment: `I want to treat the project as an app` please elaborate your intention.

Comment: @IvanStarostin: I want it to have its own views, templates etc.

Comment: A common approach is to create an app (e.g. `core`, and use this for the project's views/templates/urls instead of adding `project` to `INSTALLED_APPS`. If you really want to add the project directory to `INSTALLED_APPS` and use a namespace, I've suggested a solution in my answer below.

Comment: Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53192533/how-to-change-root-url-configuration-in-order-to-use-a-namespace-for-the-user-ur).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`app_name` does not work in the root url config. See [ticket 28413](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28413) and [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-developers/5NJS_mI7png/PsIN5oneAAAJ) on the django-developers mailing list.

If you really want to include some patterns under the `report` namespace, you can include a 2-tuple containing a list of url patterns and a namespace.

```
reports_patterns = ([
    path('myurl', views.my_view, name='myview'),
], 'reports')

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('', include(reports_patterns)
    ...
]
```

You could then use `{% url 'reports:myview' %}` in the template.

See the docs on [URL namespaces and included URLconfs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs) for more info

Answer (score 0):

you can add :

```
app_name = 'polls'
```

in above urls.py on which app your are use :

```
    urlpatterns=[
....
]
```

and then every where you need load template use:

```
{% url 'appname:index.html' %}
```

Comment: The problem is that adding `app_name` in the root `urls.py` doesn’t work

Comment: instead, add app_name in URLs.py within the app